# I/some people/people have experienced symptoms when I/they had pneumonia

Tags: present-perfect, conjunctions, past-simple

1. I **have experienced** these three symptoms *when* I **had** pneumonia.
2. I **experienced** these three symptoms *when* I **had** pneumonia.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Why all the variations? It makes the question quite hard to read. You're just asking the difference between "have experienced" and "experienced", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say there there is no significant difference in meaning between examples 1 and 2, and that both might be naturally used by fluent speakers. I think 2 would be more likely in the US at least. In this context the "have" doesn't really contribute anything, and most people would leave it out.

I suppose that technically 1 is past-perfect rather than simple past, but here the wording alone tells the listener or reader that the event is complete, so the grammatical distinction is of no importance. It becomes just a matter of style, in my view.